# Poisson Integral Formula for Upper Half Plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

It is known that the Poisson Integral Formula:

$f(x,y) = \dfrac{y}{\pi}\displaystyle\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{U(t)}{(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}}dt$

serves as a solution to the Laplace equation on the upper half plane:

$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0 & (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{2}\\ f(x,0) = U(x) & x \in \mathbb{R},\;\;  U(x) \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}),\; 1 \leq p \leq \infty \end{array} \right.$

I'm trying to justify differentiating under the integral of the solution. First I wrote the difference quotient for x and arrived at this:

$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h} = \dfrac{y}{\pi}\displaystyle\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}U(t)\dfrac{2t-2x-h}{[(x+h-t)^{2}+y^{2}][(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}]}dt$

From this however, I can't seem to establish an upper bound for the integrand in order to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. Would it be justifiable to do this:

$\left|U(t)\dfrac{2t-2x-h}{[(x+h-t)^{2}+y^{2}][(x-t)^{2}+y^{2}]}\right| \leq C\left|U(t)\right|$

where C is some constant independent of t and h? The same difficulty arises for the difference quotient for y.

Comment: No, using $U$ for the dominator is not enough since $U$ is not in $L^1$. But since $U\in L^p$ it would be enough to show that the rest of the integrand is dominated by some $g\in L^q$, where $1/p+1/q=1$. Note that you can assume $|h|\le 1$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, U is assumed to be in $L^{p}$ for $p \in [1,\infty]$.